# update function (AddWithValue parameter included) won't work

Tags: c#, ado.net

Im trying to loop over some array, and through that , update with new parameters..

this is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < wholeArr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        string[] temp = wholeArr[i].Split('-');
        UpdateQuery(int.Parse(temp[1]), int.Parse(temp[0]));



    }
```

and this is my update function :

```
public void UpdateQuery(int id, int newOrder)
{
    string sql = "update Tama38News set [OrderingNumber] = @OrderingNumber where [ID] = @ID";

    con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    con.Open();
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderingNumber", newOrder);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

the thing is, Im not getting any exception, but for some reason the DB doesnt get affected..

any idea why ?

Comment: maybe you have not  value of "@ID"'s in your data.

Comment: I do have @ID. thats strange..

Comment: `temp[1]` is `@ID` and `temp[0]` the `@OrderingNumber`? I assume that the was deliberately out of order when sending it to the `UpdateQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that temp[1] is actually the ID you want and temp[0] is the newOrder id and that you are not mixing them up.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you want to omit the last item in the array?

Change `wholeArr.Length - 1` to `wholeArr.Length`

```
for (int i = 0; i < wholeArr.Length; i++)
{
    string[] temp = wholeArr[i].Split('-');
    UpdateQuery(int.Parse(temp[1]), int.Parse(temp[0]));
}
```

Maybe there was only one item, hence the method UpdateQuery was never called. You can use the debugger to check what's going on. Set a breakpoint in the loop and press F10 to go to the next line. Inspect values in the quick-watch-window.

Apart from that, you should always dispose anything that implements `IDisposable` especially connections best with `using-statement`.

```
public void UpdateQuery(int id, int newOrder)
{
    string sql = "update Tama38News set [OrderingNumber] = @OrderingNumber where [ID] = @ID";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderingNumber", newOrder);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns 0 instead of 1? Then the id does not exist in the database or you've **mixed up id and OrderingNumber**. Have you tried to execute the query in a quick-watch-window to inspect the return value or to see whether or not an exception is thrown?

Comment: you were right!  I've mixed the id and orderingNumber!  THANKS!

Comment: @thormayer: So you've accepted the other answer altough it was posted only just whereas this for more than half an hour?